# How to combine the values which is array of the same property in the object's array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, javascript-objects

For the following array **:**

```
const a = [
  {
    26: [0],
    27: [100],
    28: [0]
  },
  {
    26: [0],
    27: [100],
    28: [0]
  },
  {
    26: [0],
    27: [100],
    28: [0]
  }
]
```

I need a function that should merge arrays with the same keys in the object.

```
`const result = [{
26: [0,0,0],
27: [100,100,100],
28: [0,0,0]
}]`
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt and note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Array reduce is your best bet. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const data = [{
    26: [0], 27: [100], 28: [0]
  },
  {
    26: [0], 27: [100], 28: [0]
  },
  {
    26: [0], 27: [100], 28: [0]
  }
];

const restructure = arr => 
  [arr.reduce((accumu, current) => {
    for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(current)) {
      accumu[key] = [...accumu[key] ?? '', ...val];
    }
    return accumu;
  }, {})];

console.log(JSON.stringify(restructure(data)));
```

Comment: Why the empty string?

Comment: @jarmod This is [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), it can convert string to array

Comment: There are no strings in this problem. Why introduce a string?

Comment: @jarmod You must have misunderstood something. This actually has nothing to do with whether the value has a string or not. When data is grouped, I use the `spread syntax` to merge the arrays. The `accumu[key]` will be undefined for the first time, so instead of using `[...accumu[key], ...val]` directly, use the `nullish coalescing operator` to replace undefined with an empty string , then `spread syntax` will convert empty string to array ( `[...'']` will be converted to `[]`), and then merged with the current array

Comment: Right, I get that but it seems somewhat obfuscated. Could you not simply use `accumu[key] = [...(accumu[key] ?? []), ...val];`?

Comment: These all work, you can replace empty strings with `[]`, you can wrap the code you want in parentheses, you can even use the `conditional (ternary) operator`, for me `...[ ]` and `...''` both use the features of the `spread syntax`, I don't think which is worse, it's like sometimes I use `for`, and sometimes I choose to use `forEach`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve this by using [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const a = [{
  26: [0],
  27: [100],
  28: [0]
}, {
  26: [0],
  27: [100],
  28: [0]
}, {
  26: [0],
  27: [100],
  28: [0]
}];

let resObj = {};

a.forEach(obj => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    resObj[key] ? resObj[key].push(...obj[key]) : resObj[key] = [...obj[key]]
  })
});

console.log([resObj]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping around a collection of utility functions can make this sort of problem nearly trivial to handle.

My solution is to write this function:

```js
const combine = reduce (mergeWith (concat)) ({})
```

based on my utility functions `reduce`, `concat`, and `mergeWith`.  Then it's as simple as:

```js
combine (a) //=> {26: [0, 0, 0], 27: [100, 100, 100], 28: [0, 0, 0]}
```

```js
const reduce = (f) => (init) => (xs) => xs .reduce ((a, x) => f (a, x), init)
const concat = (a) => (b) => a .concat (b)
const mergeWith = (f) => (a, b) => Object .fromEntries (
  [... new Set ([... Object .keys (a), ... Object .keys (b)])] .map (
    (k) => [k, k in a ? (k in b ? f (a [k]) (b [k]) : a [k]) : b [k]]
  )
)

const combine = reduce (mergeWith (concat)) ({}) 

const a = [{26: [0], 27: [100], 28: [0]}, {26: [0], 27: [100], 28: [0]}, {26: [0], 27: [100], 28: [0]}]

console .log (combine (a))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

**`reduce`** and **`concat`** do little more than convert the `Array .prototype` *methods* into pure *functions*.<sup>1</sup>  In each case, the new function is fully curried so that, for instance, you would call `reduce (tranformer) (initialValue) (values)` rather than `values .reduce (transformer, initialValue)`.  This style often makes it easier to compose functions.

**`mergeWith`** is more involved.  It performs a shallow merge of two objects, using the supplied function on the relevant properties of both objects whenever both objects have a given key, and taking the only property supplied otherwise.

Once we have these helper functions in place, then this becomes quite simple to write.  We configure `mergeWith` with `concat`, and pass this resulting function and the empty object to `reduce`.

```js
const combine = reduce (mergeWith (concat)) ({})
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>`reduce` does not supply all the parameters to the transformation function that `Array.prototype.reduce` does.  There are good reasons for this, not worth discussing here, but if you wanted them, we could simplify the implementation to just `const reduce (f) => (init) => (xs) => xs .reduce (f, init)`.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be achieved by using Javascript's inbuilt [Array.Prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) method

My solution:

```
function mergeSameKeys(arr) {
    let filteredObj = {}

    arr.map(obj => {
        let objKeys = Object.keys(obj);

        objKeys.map(key => {
            if (!filteredObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                filteredObj[key] = obj[key]
            } else {
                filteredObj[key].push(...obj[key])
            }
        })

    })

    return [filteredObj]
}

mergeSameKeys([{
    26: [0],
    27: [100],
    28: [0]
  },
  {
    26: [0],
    27: [100],
    28: [0]
  },
  {
    26: [0],
    27: [100],
    28: [0]
  }
])

// returns [{
// 26: [0,0,0],
// 27: [100,100,100],
// 28: [0,0,0]
// }]
```

The function loops over every item in the provided array and for every object it gets the names of all the objects keys using [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and returns them as a list of items in an array stored in objKeys, it then loops over every key name in objKeys and checks if the filteredObj variable contains this key as a property. If this check returns false, it creates a new key in filteredObj using this key name and setting the value of the created key to the value of the key in its original object. If the check happens to be true, it simply pushes the key's value in its original object to the key's value in the filteredObj variable. Using the [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), it pushes the actual value and not the entire array. The function returns the filteredObj variable in an array at the end and voila. Code implementation is finished.